# I built my Vuejs app by running npm run build, opening index.html throws errors: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, web-deployment, web-frontend

I ran `npm run build`, successfully created `Dist` folder, now opening index.html throws error `:Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

what can be the possible issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue JS files are not supposed to simply be opened directly in the browser (using the file:// protocol). You must use a server for it to correctly work. The simplest solution if you use Google Chrome is to use this extension: [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)

Comment: Yes this extension works fine. I also found another way, check my answer below.

Comment: Nice... didn`t know about that solution

Answer (score 3):

I found adding

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: './'
};
```

to `vue.config.js` solves it too, after which we can open `index.html` from the `dist` folder directly.

More about `publicPath` in the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath).